# How to get date & month using date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to get date & month from date. example 2017-06-15 so I want date & month i.e. -06-15. Do u have any idea? Really appreciated.

From Below query I am getting month from date. but I want both date & month

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(`date`) AS month_name FROM table_name;
```

Comment: use DATE(`date`)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '-%m-%d') AS month_name FROM table_name;
```

see the [date_format documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) to see all the possible formats

Comment: Its working. Thanks!

Comment: Someone that actually read the question +1

Comment: if i want to display data from date & month?? SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE dob = '-06-06';

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '-%m-%d') = '-06-06'

Comment: Thank you Eduard!

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL MONTH() returns the MONTH for the date within a range of 1 to 12
>   ( January to December). It Returns 0 when MONTH part for the date is
>   0.

```
SELECT MONTH('2009-05-18');
```

> MySQL DAY() returns the day of the month for a specified date. The day
>   returned will be within the range of 1 to 31. If the given date is
>   ‘0000-00-00’, the function will return 0. The DAYOFMONTH() is the
>   synonym of DAY().

```
SELECT DAY('2008-05-15');
```

Link : [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select month('2017-06-15'),DAY('2017-06-15')
```

Comment: Please explain your answer code on it's own is useless explain how it helps the OP with there problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
DATEPART(datepart,date)
```

use below query

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,datecolumn) AS dateYear,
DATEPART(mm,datecolumn) AS dateMonth,
DATEPART(dd,datecolumn) AS dateDay
FROM table_name
```